# How can I 'provide' a void method in Dagger

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to migrate a project from Spring and starting to play with Dagger 2 by following a sample GitHub repo.

In Spring I can use an annotation at the class level to expose all of the methods of a class, including `void` methods. I want to do this in Dagger 2 i.e., I want to 'provide' a `void` method.

In the code example below maybe I should move the `printRandomUUID` method to the `Printer` interface. However, I'm doing this little exercise with the goal of migrating a classical Spring `@Component` or `@Service`.

What is the correct approach? Is it possible to provide a void method at component or module level?

```
public class Main {

 interface Printer {

    void printMsg(String msg);
 }

 static class ConsolePrinter implements Printer {

    @Override
    public void printMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
 }

 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = ConsoleModule.class)
 interface HelloWorldApp {

    Printer getPrinter();

    //this doesn't compile -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid component method:
    void printRandomUUID();
 }

 @Module
 static class ConsoleModule {

    @Provides
    Printer providePrinter() {
        return new ConsolePrinter();
    }

    //this doesn't compile -> @Provides methods must return a value (not void)
    @Provides
    void printRandomUUID() {
        System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloWorldApp app = DaggerMain_HelloWorldApp.create();
    app.getPrinter().printMsg("Hello");
    System.out.println("-");
    //app.printRandomUUID();//here i want a void method to be consumed, from the component.
 }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a super weird thing to want.  Can you just provide a `Runnable` callback instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible (yet). Unlike with Spring, Dagger is only configured by inspecting the Component interface and Modules. This means that Dagger `@Component` methods have to [match the format of the methods from the `@Component` documentation](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#component-methods), and there's currently no way of providing arbitrary code or methods that delegate to other instances.

That's not to say Components can't have void methods: They can, but they're required to be one-parameter methods that inject `@Inject`-annotated methods and fields in externally-created instances. These are known as [members-injection methods](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods), and instead of `void` they can also return the type they accept for ease of chaining.

From a different standpoint, I would argue that combining arbitrary business logic with your Dagger-created component is a bad idea for reasons of simplicity and correctness:

- To do so may be violating SRP or separation-of-concerns: One of the stated advantages of dependency injection is the separation of object-creation logic from other business logic. Allowing the addition of a business method on an object-creation Component should feel as improper as the use of `new` in a business component. (Whether or not every single object should be provided through a DI graph is a contentious topic for another day.)
- If you hold to best practices and avoid side-effects and other "heavy lifting" in constructors/factories/providers, then you should be able to reason cleanly about what can and can't happen from within a Component method. Allowing for arbitrary methods--particularly void methods--on a Component would be antithetical to that practice.
- If your application uses separate granular libraries instead of a monolithic compilation step, then consuming a Component from within its own object graph may make it hard to build without introducing a dependency cycle. Of course, Dagger does allows for the injection of a component within its own graph, but doing so recklessly may cause cycle problems later.
- Similar use-cases are so easy to represent using existing structures--making a Runnable available through the graph as Louis Wasserman commented, or injecting a similar single-purpose object to hold the method--that keeping arbitrary implementations off of the Component seems to result in no big loss of functionality or readability. At worst, you need one extra method call to get to a class you define.

If I were migrating as you are, I would make a class adjacent to HelloWorldApp called HelloWorldMethods, and shift all of the methods I would put on HelloWorldApp onto that instead. If this is a common pattern in your Spring migration, you might even define a local convention for it (FooComponent comes with FooMethods or FooUtil, for instance). Finally, if you wanted to hide the Dagger implementation details (as in an external API) you could also write your own class that wraps and consumes your Component, delegating important methods to the inner Component and providing whichever arbitrary implementations you need.

Comment: The FooMethods aproach is what I was looking for. As I'm doing baby steps with Dagger, I realize that 'the way of thinking' should be different, I mean a classic service layer with spring, is not directly translatable to Dagger way of DI.

Comment: @whyem Right, Dagger components are a great way to provide services or instantiate services, but they aren't very good at all at being services themselves. On the plus side, you get clearer control over exactly what service interfaces and implementations look like, necessarily separate from the component interface.